# Failed to install "iOS 6.1 Simulator" XCode 5

Tags: ios-simulator, ios6.1, xcode5

I want to run my app on both simulators ios6 and ios7. I'm trying to install ios 6 simulator but I am getting this error:

```
Failed to install "iOS 6.1 Simulator"
An unknown error occured. Please try again later.
```

I restarted XCode but not working stil..

Comment: How are you installing it?  XCode can be kind of quirky at times and requires a computer restart to fix all of its settings?

Comment: Well you are using beta software which is likely to be buggy. Can I assume you're running the latest version?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Yes, I'm using the last version.

Comment: @JeffCompton I am trying to install components in Preferences>>Download section.

Comment: I have the 6.1 and 7.0 sdks and everything works.  I had to restart my computer though.

Comment: Reboot your Mac and try again.

Comment: Reboot didn't help me. Did somebody resolve this issue?

Answer (score 88):

Try to reset iOS 6.1 simulator from menu "iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...",

then run your app in XCode. This helped me.

Comment: Good call doh! Not liking xcode 5...or ios 7 for that matter :-(

Comment: This works for me but the error comes back very frequently using Xcode 5.

Comment: where is the ios simulator menu?

Comment: @Odelya click on the simulator window, the menu will be on top of the screen

Comment: It's mostly occurring when you pull new changes from remote..

At least for me.

Comment: When we want to work with both ios 6 and ios 7 it will work fine.I have tried it and its working fine for me, Thank you..

Answer (score 5):

Was having the same problem ,

already did a system restart and reset the simulator but didn't work

but

deleting the app manually inside the simulator worked for me,

Comment: Yes, deleting the app from the simulator worked for me as well.  Thanks.

Comment: +1, note that only deleting the app does not work - you need to reset the simulator as well.

Answer (score 5):

Run it in iOS 7 simulator (so you can run it), once there, go to "Hardware > Device > select some iOS 6 or earlier device", then apply the "iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings..."

Answer (score 3):

I got exact same problem and solved by using following way,

1. Launch the iOS Simulator
2. Go and click "iOS Simulator" Menu
3. Click "Reset content and settings"
4. Close simulator and rebuild your app.

[image]

Above screen shot is showing the way how you can do this...

I think this works for you...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after update to XCode 5.
Running an application on the available iOS 7 Simulator and setting the "Enable this mac for developing" check in the popup has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XIB or Storyboard. You have to set document type to "XCode 4.6"

choose storyboard -> inspector (right pane) -> first tab (identity and type)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had the exact the same issue. I restart my Mac and I'm now download it.

**EDIT**: I tried everything else. I'm sorry not to be able to answer by given a more useful option.

Comment: Did you try Resetting the simulator ?

Comment: @yunas yes, and it didn't help. Only restarting my Mac Book Pro. :(

Comment: 1. Reset simulator  2. Clean dependencies  3. Clean derived data 4. you are all set to go... restarting machine is just too mainstream...

Comment: @yunas I agree. Now it's fixed.