# Xcode 5 not showing Scheme option to run Simulator on iOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode 5 is behaving just fine, and I'm able to build and run apps on my iOS 7 device and in the iOS 7 simulator.

However, I do want to support iOS 6.1, but I don't see any way to build and run the apps for an iOS 6 simulator.

Things wot I've done:

- Set Deployment Target to 6.1 for [both Project and Target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123205)
- Downloaded iOS 6 Simulator
- [Copied the iOS 6 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424950) into Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
- [Reset Content and Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736338/2284713) for the simulator

Originally, I was trying to see the app in the iOS 6 simulator by switching from iOS 7 to iOS 6 in the Hardware > Device menu in the iOS Simulator application, but there aren't any apps in the iOS 6 simulator.

I'm gathering from answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19123205) that there should be something I can select before I click Build/Run.

I'd love to be able to see my apps in both iOS 6 and 7 simulators. Any ideas what I'm missing? Here's a [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4laxN.jpg) to what I see when I click on the simulator dropdown.

Comment: Having this trouble in 2014 with iOS 8

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turns out the solution was changing the deployment target for the project from iOS 6.1 to iOS 6.0, upon which the simulator scheme selection immediately showed the option to choose iOS 6 or 7 simulators. Basically the deployment target should match a simulator version that you have installed.

Thanks to random commenters in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040825/i-have-installed-ios6-simulator-in-xcode5-but-i-cant-run-app-on-ios6-simulator) who mentioned that that worked for them.

Comment: I also just started having this issue... however switching my deployment to 6.0 did not aleviate the problem... still no access to 6.0 simulators

Comment: actually... looks like I needed to redownoad the simulators again from within Xcode prefs as the new version of xcode invalidated my last simulators.

Answer (score 9):

All you have to do is go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Choose the "Downloads" tab and install the iOS 6.0 Simulator.

Once you're done downloading it, it should show up as an option in your schemes.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, Matt, but I did do that. I've added a link to my OP (at the end) showing what I see when I try to choose simulators.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure then. Did you try to completely close out XCode? Also, could you take a screenshot of the tab when you click on More Simulators... option in your screenshot?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply -- yup, I've completely closed Xcode at least a few times. Here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/xsZ3KVa) to what I see when I click on that option.

Comment: Yeah, my only suggestion left is to remove xcode 5 and redownload it.

Comment: That seems fair... especially since I've yet to see anyone else with the same issue. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Matt, just FYI -- I did try redownloading/reinstalling, but turns out the fix was changing the deployment target from 6.1 to 6.0. So strange.

Answer (score 9):

Just a little caveat....I tried what you said but it didn't work for me...
Changed Deployment Target on "Project" from 7.1 to 6.0

Then I realised that Deployment Target was still set to 7.1 on the "Target" - once I changed that it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Click to target or project > Build Settings > Achitecture > Supported Plateforms  : change to iOS

Answer (score 3):

What I did to get mine working was click on the scheme to the left of where the Simulators usually appear in the dropdown, then choose edit scheme.

A new window will display, make sure that Run is highlighted on the left and then click on the Info tab. Choose the .app file for Executable.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a solution here's what worked for me:

- From the xcode beta's pull down menus, Xcode > Open Developer Tool >
  iOS Simulator (if you get a pop up error just dismiss it)
- Once in the Simulator go to Hardware > Device > Manage Devices.
- Delete everything listed under simulator.
- Reboot your machine.
- After that navigate back to Manage Devices in the simulator and click the plus to add back
  your simulators. Then the iOS 8 simulators will show up.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This might help u out better..you have to copy paste iPhoneOS6.1sdk folder. This is for SDK, similarly instead of iPhoneOS.platform select iPhoneSimulator.platform and then the same path.

Comment: I did copy/paste the iPhoneOS 6.1 SDK folder. I didn't do this for the iPHoneSimulator folder, but I did do an install, similar to how Matt Tang mentioned. I'll check to see if there's a difference.

Comment: I didn't do a copy for the the simulator, but the install added an iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk folder next to the 7.0 one, like you described.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your "Deployment Target" is higher than the ones available on your simulators.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xcode5 neither has 6.0 SDK or 6.0 simulator. But what you can do is u can copy both 6.0SDK and 6.0 simulator from your previous Xcodes (xcode4.5 for 6.0 and XCode4.6 for ios6.1) You can find the simulator at /applications/xcode.app/contents/developer/platforms/iphonesimulator.platform/developer/applications/iphone simulator.app

And SDK at /applications/xcode.app/contents/developer/platforms/iphoneos.platform/devicesupport/6.0

Copy the entire folders for simulator and SDK in the exact same path of XCode5.
Note: to go the the Contents of Xcode.app just do a right click on the .app file and you will get an option"Show Contents".

Once u are done copy pasting, restart ur XCode5 and u can see 6.0/6.1 simulator as an option :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your project root.
2. Then Go to the Build settings.
3. Then set iOS deployment target 5.0
4. Then select iphone6 on top left of your project.

   [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL7fF.png)

Answer (score -1):

Solved restoring an older version of the xcodeproj file.