# Simulator list disappears in Xcode 6.1 after installing Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode6.1, xcode6.3

I downloaded new Xcode 6.3 and while installation (with drag-n-drop feature, not using App-Store) it asked me if I want to keep both or replace the old Xcode 6.1. I kept both for some reasons. But after installation new Xcode 6.3 works fine but I'm missing simulator list in  old Xcode 6.1. It only shows `iOS Device` on the list.
 Yes, I created and replaced with several new scheme, tried to edit it. Also tried to add simulators from ***Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> iOS Simulator*** an then ***Hardware > Device > Manage Devices*** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187192/xcode-5-not-showing-scheme-option-to-run-simulator-on-ios-6) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2b9j2p/xcode_6_missing_ios_8_simulator/). In this process simulator even shows up. I checked package contents of Xcode 6.1. Platforms (both OS and Simulator) are all there. I know I can restore it by deleting from application folder and reinstall it. But if there any way so I can get and make work simulators for xcode 6.1 without reinstall it? And What is the reason behind this simulator disappearance? I'm guessing PATH  issue. Am I right? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I would say Xcode is now corrupt after choosing to *Keep Both*, which merges the files in the two apps, as far as I'm aware.

You need to download both Xcode 6.1.1 and 6.3 from the Apple Developer Downloads site and install them using separate names:

1. Delete the existing `/Applications/Xcode.app`.
2. Drag Xcode 6.1.1 into `/Applications` and then rename it `Xcode611.app`.
3. Drag Xcode 6.3 into `/Applications` and then rename it `Xcode63.app`.
4. Add both to your Dock as desired.

Comment: yes, that make sense. It may have corrupted `Xcode 6.1.1` on **Keep Both** action. Thanks.